# How to access views in the Layouts after bounding the layouts to viewPager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-viewpager

I'm in a typical situation where I've bounded 6 layouts in a viewPager and have put that viewPager in my activity. actually these are 6 different forms of a registration process.
the code of the viewPagerAdapter is something like this:

```
public class IndiRegFormsAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

public int getCount() {
    return 6;
}

public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);




    int resId = 0;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        resId = R.layout.indi_reg_view_1;
        break;
    case 1:
        resId = R.layout.indi_reg_view_2;
        break;
    case 2:
        resId = R.layout.indi_reg_view_3;
        break;
    case 3:
        resId = R.layout.indi_reg_view_4;
        break;
    case 4:
        resId = R.layout.indi_reg_view_5;
        break;
    case 5:
        resId = R.layout.indi_reg_view_6;
        break;
    }

    View view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);

    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
    ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);

}


@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
    return arg0 == ((View) arg1);

}

@Override
public Parcelable saveState() {
    return null;
}
}
```

and my activity code snippet where I've used this viewPager is like:

```
    adapter = new IndiRegFormsAdapter();
    myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.indiregforms);
    myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    myPager.setCurrentItem(0);
```

the items are bounded in the viewPager, all 6 layouts.. But the problem is how to access all edit texts and switches and all the controls in those 6 layouts from activity.. I have to save data using those forms.. but unfortunately do not know how to access them all..

please help me with this or suggest any other thing to bound the layouts in the view pager and access all controls in all layouts..

Comment: for that you have to user Fragments with viewpager buddy that can allow you individually to access all views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go for Fragment View Pager. Then Create fragment for each of the form layouts and handle data for each inside the fragment as well (Just like an activity). Then use fragmentviewpagerAdapter and you should be good.

Comment: can you suggest any example URL link so that I can see that and try.?